# sql to get rows based on a combination of values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Status      Agency  Policy  
---------   ------  ------
Submitted   Ag1     AAA

Rated       Ag1     AAA 

Lost        Ag1     AAA 

Issued      Ag1     AAA 

Submitted   Ag1     BBB 

Rated       Ag1     BBB 

Lost        Ag2     BBB 

Issued      Ag1     BBB
```

I have this data for example…
"For a policy if there is a combination of both Lost and Issued from the same agency then I don’t want the Lost record 
but if the policy has both lost and Issued from different agency then I want all the records

Result set :

```
Status      Agency  Policy  
---------   ------  ------
Submitted   Ag1     AAA

Rated       Ag1     AAA 

Issued      Ag1     AAA 

Submitted   Ag1     BBB 

Rated       Ag1     BBB 

Lost        Ag2     BBB 

Issued      Ag1     BBB
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected result-set in your question? Like are the expected result for Agency1?

Comment: No. So if a policy has both lost ans issued for the same agent then discard the lost row but if  a policy has both lost and written for different agents then have everything

Comment: There is a difference between the two currents answer. If Policy "AAA" had a Agency "Ag2" with "lost" record, would you like this record to included or not? Currently my answer excluded it as a combination already exists for "AAA".  Erik's answer include it.

Comment: If Policy "AAA" had a Agency "Ag2" with "lost" record - YES I want to count it .       Also there is a another part -  the same concept has to be applied to a status of "Declined and Issued" combination as well.   (i.e) for a policy, agent , if there is (Declined and Issued ) or (Lost and Issued) then discard the "Lost" and "Declined"

Comment: IF  (Declined and Issued )exists, then discard both Lost and Declined or just Declined?

Comment: If Declined, Lost and Issued exists for the same policy with same agency then keep only the Issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bellow where clause do the following :
When Status is not lost, always return the record.
When Status is lost, then check if agency doesn't have any agency with the combination of 'Lost' and 'Issued' to return the record.

```
DECLARE @t  TABLE(  [Status] NVARCHAR(50),
                    Agency   NVARCHAR(50),
                    Policy   NVARCHAR(50))


INSERT INTO @t
VALUES(
'Submitted',    'Ag1',     'AAA'),
('Rated',       'Ag1',     'AAA'), 
('Lost',        'Ag1',     'AAA'), 
('Issued',      'Ag1',     'AAA'), 
('Lost',        'Ag2',     'AAA'), 
('Submitted',   'Ag1',     'BBB'), 
('Rated',       'Ag1',     'BBB'), 
('Lost',        'Ag2',     'BBB'), 
('Issued',      'Ag1',     'BBB'), 
('Lost',        'Ag0',     'CCC')

--In the bellow "Select", replace "@t" with your table.
SELECT *
FROM @t AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                    FROM   @t AS sub
                    WHERE  sub.Policy = t.Policy
                    AND    sub.Agency = t.Agency
                    AND    sub.[Status] = 'Issued' )
OR [Status] NOT IN ('Lost', 'Declined')
```

Result :

```
Submitted   Ag1 AAA
Rated       Ag1 AAA
Issued      Ag1 AAA
Lost        Ag2 AAA
Submitted   Ag1 BBB
Rated       Ag1 BBB
Lost        Ag2 BBB
Issued      Ag1 BBB
Lost        Ag0 CCC
```

Comment: If there were 2 records for 'Lost', it would omit those records

Comment: Thank you !.. This seems to work but with a small problem... It also discards polices if it just has a row for  "Lost" ...I want to discard the "Lost" only when an Issued is present... If there is no issued for a policy then the lost record should be retained

Comment: @sara 
It does handle policy with only one lost record. Just so you see, I added policy 'CCC' to my exemple. However, it didn't handle one lost record by Agency like stated in the question's comment section. 

I also edited my answer, so now it does. I added agency "ag2" to policy "AAA" to test this case as well.

Comment: In the result set I want to see "Lost      Ag2     AAA"    and   " Lost     Ag0    CCC".....  but the result set doesn't have those

Comment: @sara 
Oups... I forgot to update the result section of my answer with the latest clarification. I adjusted the result section now.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery could be used to filter "Lost" records when a matching "Issued" record exists for the same agency and policy.

```
SELECT  Status, Agency, Policy
FROM    YourTable AS t1
WHERE   Status NOT IN ( 'Lost', 'Declined' )
OR      NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM   YourTable AS t2
            WHERE  t2.Agency = t1.Agency
            AND    t2.Policy = t1.Policy
            AND    t1.Status IN ( 'Lost', 'Declined' )
            AND    t2.Status = 'Issued' )
```

Comment: Erik, Thank you!!.... This one works as well except for the same problem. If there is another row   "Lost      Ag3       CCC"   then I want to retain it... but the query discards it.

Comment: Based on this SqlFiddle, it still gets that row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87691/1